# How do one work with third party resources in ARM templates?

Tags: azure-resource-manager

I'm trying to find out where can I find template reference for SendGrid resource in Azure. It's possible to deploy SendGrid through ARM but I can not find any documentation with details about parameters etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample of SendGrid account for you.

```
{
    "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "name": {
            "type": "String"
        },
        "location": {
            "type": "String"
        },
        "plan_name": {
            "type": "String"
        },
        "plan_publisher": {
            "type": "String"
        },
        "plan_product": {
            "type": "String"
        },
        "plan_promotion_code": {
            "type": "String"
        },
        "password": {
            "type": "SecureString"
        },
        "email": {
            "type": "String"
        },
        "firstName": {
            "type": "String"
        },
        "lastName": {
            "type": "String"
        },
        "company": {
            "type": "String"
        },
        "website": {
            "type": "String"
        },
        "acceptMarketingEmails": {
            "type": "String"
        },
        "tags": {
            "type": "Object"
        }
    },
    "resources": [{
        "type": "Sendgrid.Email/accounts",
        "apiVersion": "2015-01-01",
        "name": "[parameters('name')]",
        "location": "[parameters('location')]",
        "tags": "[parameters('tags')]",
        "plan": {
            "name": "[parameters('plan_name')]",
            "publisher": "[parameters('plan_publisher')]",
            "product": "[parameters('plan_product')]",
            "promotionCode": "[parameters('plan_promotion_code')]"
        },
        "properties": {
            "password": "[parameters('password')]",
            "acceptMarketingEmails": "[parameters('acceptMarketingEmails')]",
            "email": "[parameters('email')]",
            "firstName": "[parameters('firstName')]",
            "lastName": "[parameters('lastName')]",
            "company": "[parameters('company')]",
            "website": "[parameters('website')]"
        }
    }]
}
```

Comment: Is there documentation for it?

Comment: @GregorySuvalian No, but you can deploy the sendgrid account in the portal manually, then in the resource group -> `Deployments` -> find the deployment -> `Template`, you can find the template.

Comment: Thanks. I really want to create API keys etc so was looking for details documentations.